# Python. Как удалённо управлять программой?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Для примера на сайте `www.pythonanywhere.com` запущу программу:

```
def func(text):
    print(text)
```

как вызвать `func` и передать параметр `text`?

Answer (score 1):

```py
def func(text):
    print(text)
com = input() 
txt = input()
if com == 'f':
    func(txt)
```